# Can we programmatically switch on/off NFC in react native?

Tags: react-native, nfc

I am trying to programmatically switching on/off NFC but I could not find anything in the documentation . This command NfcManager.goToNfcSetting() takes me to settings where I can manually switch on/off NFC . Secondly how to check whether NFC is enabled or not?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to turn NFC on/off programmatically as this is seen as a privacy risk

NfcManager has `isSupported` and `isEnabled` methods.